# Haxe unit testing for the C# target

Tags: haxe

Being new to Haxe I'm trying to run munit tests for the C# target. Initially, I ran `haxelib run munit config` and successfully executed tests in JavaScript and C++. I grabbed test.hxml straight from the example generated by the 'config' command.

When adapted to C#, `haxe run munit test` does practically nothing (only prints *Massive Unit - Copyright 2017 Massive Interactive. Version 2.1.2* to console).

Is this expected behavior? Is something not supported for C# as of now? How do I run unit tests written in Haxe for C# target?

Below is modified test.hxml:

```
# CSharp
-main TestMain
-lib munit
-lib hamcrest
-cp src

-cp test
-cs build/csharp_test
```

Also, please notice that I have no issues compiling to C# target in general, as well as executing apps built for C# target.

Haxe version: *3.4.2 (git build master @ 890f8c7)*

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK original MUnit does not support C#.
Check this fork of MUnit https://github.com/SlavaRa/MUnit2017
Fork author claims support for all Haxe targets.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try https://github.com/haxetink/tink_unittest.
It supports multiple targets.